# jQuery.mmenu dragOpen disable dragging at desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, drag-and-drop, nav

jQuery.mmenu uses Hammer.js for dragging, in the [docs jQuery.mmenu says](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/addons/drag-open.html)

> Hammer.js enables dragging on touch and desktop devices. If you only want to enable dragging the menu open on touchscreens, use the $.mmenu.support.touch variable.

I definitely want to disable dragging for desktops and use it's behaviour only at mobile. It says i shoud use `$.mmenu.support.touch` to do so. But how to use it? I've tried all possible scenarios, used any type there, placed it before and after plugin initialisation, but without luck.

How to use `$.mmenu.support.touch` to disable opening menu by mouse dragging on desktops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for an answer to this too and figured it out just now.
This is my whole configuration.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#mmenu-left").mmenu(
                        {
                            extensions: ["theme-dark"],
                            dragOpen: { open: ($.mmenu.support.touch?true:false) }
                        },
                        {
                            offCanvas: {
                                pageSelector: "#thepage"
                            }
                        }
                    );
            });
```

This is the part for that enables dragopen only on touch devices:

`dragOpen: { open: ($.mmenu.support.touch?true:false) }`

Comment: I don't need this info anymore but will hope it would be helpful for someone else, thanks.